# USB drive autorun.inf

Tags: windows, usb, autoplay

I've got 2 identical USB drives with identical files... including the autorun.inf.

Yet upon insertion 1 comes up with the Autoplay menu & the other opens a usb contents window.

Why would this occur? Is this Windows based behaviour - not how the USB is setup?

Ideally i'd like both to open the Autoplay menu.

Comment: "I've got 2 identical USB drives with ... [different behaviour]" - ergo, you have two different USB drives.

Comment: same size, same manufacturer, same looking, different drives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have configured one drive to open the contents instead of running Autoplay.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I created a new Windows admin account, logged in & tried the 2 drives... both came up with the Autoplay menu. Not sure how I changed the default action, or how to change it back, but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

**have you cheked the contents of autorun.inf file.**

Autorun.inf file is used to define the action while inserting the removable device in windows. so carefully compare the autorun.inf file

Comment: They're exactly the same file.